# How to delete variable captured in closure class

Tags: python, scoping

See the following two functions, the first one returns a function closure, the second one a "class closure". `objects` is used to track the created objects. In both cases an instance of `MyObject` is captured in the closure.

```
import weakref

class MyObject(object):
    pass

def leak1():
    obj = MyObject()
    objects[id(obj)] = weakref.ref(obj)

    def inner():
        return obj

    return inner

def leak2():
    obj = MyObject()
    objects[id(obj)] = weakref.ref(obj)

    class Inner(object):

        __slots__ = () # edit

        def __call__(self):
            return obj

        #def __del__(self):
        #   nonlocal obj
        #   del obj

    return Inner()

def print_all_objects(s):
    for id, ref in objects.items():
        print(s, id, ref())

for leak in (leak1, leak2):
    print(leak.__name__)
    objects = {}
    a = leak()
    print_all_objects(1)
    del a
    print_all_objects(2)
```

If you run this, you get the following output:

```
leak1
(1, 54150256L, <__main__.MyObject object at 0x00000000033A4470>)
(2, 54150256L, None)
leak2
(1, 54150256L, <__main__.MyObject object at 0x00000000033A4470>)
(2, 54150256L, <__main__.MyObject object at 0x00000000033A4470>)
```

That means in the first case `obj` is deleted after the function closure is deleted (which is what I expected).
In the second case however `obj` is never deleted. This can be fixed in Python 3 by using `nonlocal` and `__del__`, but not in Python 2.7 as `nonlocal` does not exist.

So my question: Why is the captured variable not deleted in the case of the class; and: how can I delete it in Python 2.7 without using some weird tracking mechanism using `weakref`?

Comment: The standard trick is to set `obj_wrap = [obj]` outside, then you can use `return obj_wrap[0]` and `obj_wrap[0] = None` inside to modify the outer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.

CPython uses a combination of reference counting and a garbage collector to dispose of unneeded objects. In the first case, deleting the closure with `del a` reduces the refcount of the leaked object to 0 and it is immediately disposed. In the second case, there is a reference cycle between the `Inner` class, its `__call__` method, and `obj`. This reference cycle prevents the refcount from dropping to 0, so the closure isn't *immediately* deleted. But once the garbage collector starts its next collection cycle, the closure *will* be disposed of.

If you want to delete the closure immediately, you can manually trigger the garbage collection with [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect):

```
import gc

for leak in (leak1, leak2):
    print(leak.__name__)
    objects = {}
    a = leak()
    print_all_objects(1)
    del a
    gc.collect()  # <- add this
    print_all_objects(2)
```

Output:

```
leak1
1 140591616726800 <__main__.MyObject object at 0x7fde095f9710>
2 140591616726800 None
leak2
1 140591619339880 <__main__.MyObject object at 0x7fde09877668>
2 140591619339880 None
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I am still not clear why there is a ref circle. Why does `obj` hold any references, and why does it not do so in case of a normal function?

Comment: @C.Yduqoli The reference cycle is actually just the `Inner` class holding a reference to itself through its `__dict__`. I don't know _why_ the `__dict__` has a reference to the class, but that's how it is. So since the class is kept alive by this reference cycle, it also keeps the `__call__` method alive, which in turn keeps `obj` alive.

Comment: If I use `__slots__` to make the `__dict__` go away, the circle is still there...

Comment: @C.Yduqoli I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I added `__slots__` to my code above. I tested with python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli I'm not sure, but I *think* the class is referencing itself in its [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order): Printing `Inner.__mro__` gives you `(<class '__main__.leak2.<locals>.Inner'>, <class 'object'>)`. If that's not a weak reference (or dynamically generated), then you won't be able to write a class that _doesn't_ have a reference cycle.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue17950 actually describes precisely this behavior. But it's closed without a fix. Oh well I will just live with it. Thanks for your insights.